# Проблема с DataGridView

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview

Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.

```html
       private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 Sell = new Form3();
            Form2 ysl = new Form2();

            n = Sell.dataGridView1.RowCount;
            if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                label13.Text = ysl.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[4].Value.ToString();//=sum;
                sum = label13.Text;

                int yy = Int32.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                int y = Int32.Parse(label14.Text);
                if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
                {
                    label14.Text = Convert.ToString((y) * 95 / 100);
                  Ошибка ссылается на эту строку//  label13.Text = Convert.ToString(Int32.Parse(sum) * 95 / 100);
                    Sell.table1TableAdapter.Insert(n + 1, textBox4.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox1.Text, yy, y);// textBox.Text);
                    MessageBox.Show("Операция выполнена успешна");
                }
```

В DataGridView2 4 столбца заполнены 3 строки!

Comment: Какая строчка кидает ошибку?

Comment: @МстиславПавлов ошибся в описании. ошибка в данной строке label13.Text = ysl.dataGridView2.Rows[1].Cells[4].Value.ToString();

Answer (score 1):

Вы написали, что у вас 4 столбца, в своем же коде, вы пытаетесь сослаться в 5-й столбец, которого не существует, по этому вы и получаете ошибку. Напомню, что нумерация в начинается с нуля.